# Usage of array with MySQL Rails 4

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, arrays

I am trying to change in my "seeker_cvs" table column "location_id". It was an integer type. Now I want to make it as an array. (I am forced to make it without many-to-many association). So my model is:

```
class SeekerCv < ActiveRecord::Base

  belongs_to :location, class_name: 'Category'
  serialize :location_id, Array

end
```

Category has many seeker_cvs.

Also I have added and run new migration:

```
class ChangeLocationIdOnSeekerCvs < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    change_column :seeker_cvs, :location_id, :integer, array: true, default: []
  end
end
```

In seekers_cvs controller I have changed in permit "location_id" to "location_id: []":

```
class SeekerCvsController < ApplicationController

  def new
    @cv = SeekerCv.new
  end

  def create
    @cv = SeekerCv.new(cv_params)
    @cv.seeker = current_seeker
    if @cv.save
      redirect_to seeker_cv_path(@cv)
    else
      render :new
    end
  end

  def edit
    @cv = SeekerCv.find(params[:id])
    authorize @cv
  end

  def update
    @cv = SeekerCv.find(params[:id])
    @cv.attributes = cv_params
    if @cv.save
      redirect_to seeker_cv_path(@cv)
    else
      render :edit
    end
  end

  private

  def cv_params
    params.require(:seeker_cv).permit :name,
                                      :category_id,
                                      :no_experience,
                                      location_id: []
  end
end
```

In view I added `multiple: true` to form:

```
= simple_form_for @cv, html: { class: 'form-horizontal' } do |f|
  .panel.panel-default
    .panel-heading
      h3.panel-title = t('.cv_name')
    .panel-body#cv-category
      = f.input :name
      = f.input :category_id do
        = f.select :category_id,
          nested_set_options_opt_mod(Category.category.root.children.to_a) { |i| "#{'-' * i.level} #{i.name}" },
          { disabled: Category.category.find_all { |l| !l.leaf? }.map(&:id), include_blank: true },
          { class: 'form-control' }
      = f.input :location_id do
        = f.select :location_id,
          nested_set_options_opt(Category.location.root) { |i| "#{'-' * i.level} #{i.name}" },
          { disabled: Category.location.root.id, include_blank: true }, 
          { multiple: true, class: 'form-control' }
```

But when I am trying to create or update seeker_cv (see picture) I am getting:

```
ActiveRecord::SerializationTypeMismatch at /app/en/seeker_cvs
Attribute was supposed to be a Array, but was a Fixnum. -- 0
```

[image: Error]

P.S. I need to hold previously created seeker_cvs with location_id with integer type. And new one or updated has to have column with array type

Comment: I think the column type has to be a varchar, because mysql doesn't have a native array datatype.

Comment: `change_column :seeker_cvs, :location_id, :string`

Comment: Iceman, thank you! Your solution works great. Now I have changed my column to array type

Comment: Great, I made an answer to wrap things up :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that `mysql` doesn't have a native array type. So you have to use `varchar` as a column type

```
change_column :seeker_cvs, :location_id, :string
```